# Measure exact time breakdown of http request in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, http

I have a HTTP request in my `Asp.net MVC` app with some code like below:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com/get");
request.Method = "GET";
using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
    var body = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    //my logic ...
}
```

So I'm wondering if there is any solution to find out request exact time breakdown like [Google Chrome Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference#network-conditions). If I want to be honest, I need these times:

- DNS Lookup
- Initial connection
- Request sent
- Waiting (TTFB)
- Content Download

Google Chrome Developers Tools example:
[image: Google Chrome Developers Tools example]